# What's the best way to get the input of a text box if the function grabbing the input is already called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The title might be hard to understand, so I'll explain it here.

I have a function called addition, which gives problems to the user. It displays questions like "4+5", and to evaluate the answer, I have an input box.

The addition function is already called, but how could I get the value of the answer in the text box? I tried using jQuery to listen to the enter button, but I'm not sure how I could relay that information (the answer) back to the other addition function.

Here is an example of what it looks like:

[image]

Here is some of the code I'm using:

```
<input class="answer" id="input" type="text">
```

JS:

```
function addition()  { //addition function



   for(i=cookiearray[1]; i>0;i--) { //uses cookies from previous page

   var n1= Math.floor(Math.random() * (cookiearray[3] - cookiearray[2]) + cookiearray[2]); //creates cookie

   //random number between user's min and max
   var n2= Math.floor(Math.random() * (cookiearray[3] - cookiearray[2]) + cookiearray[2]);

   document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = n1 + "+" + n2 + "=" ; //displays to page
```

Comment: can you give the JS code as well ?

Comment: what code have you tried so far? What attributes are on the textbox? Any of these https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors that apply to your input will work in jQuery and `document.querySelector()`

Comment: When you call the *addition* function, it should generate the question and its answer. The answer should be saved in a global variable. Then, you simply have a handler monitoring the input box and it checks its value against the answer once the Enter key is pressed. Does that resolve your problem?

Comment: I think this would solve it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also look for an ENTER key press and then check the current focused element. But for now - just have them click a button when they want to check their answer:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myBtn').click(function(){
      if(calculatedAnswer == $('myInput').val()){
         //correct answer
      } else {
         //incorrect answer
      }
   });
})
```

and if you know what question you are asking - you can just calculate it on the fly?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#myBtn').click(function(){
      var question_id = document.getActiveElement.id //something to this effect
      var calculatedAnswer = calculate_answer(question_id);
      if(calculatedAnswer == $('myInput').val()){
         //correct answer
      } else {
         //incorrect answer
      }
   });
})
```

Comment: If calculatedAnswer was a variable in another JS file and inside a function, would this code still be able to access that variable?

Comment: no - If you are serving mathematical problems like that - why not just calculate the correct answer at the same time you check if THEIR answer is correct?

Comment: Hey Dan, I got it to work! I used your logic and paired it with the logic of another answer and it helped me solve the problem!

Answer (score 0):

If the id of your textbox is answer, you would do

```
//Declare a global variable
var answer;
function addition()  { //addition function
    for(i=cookiearray[1]; i>0;i--) { //uses cookies from previous page

    var n1= Math.floor(Math.random() * (cookiearray[3] - cookiearray[2]) + cookiearray[2]); //creates cookie

   //random number between user's min and max
   var n2= Math.floor(Math.random() * (cookiearray[3] - cookiearray[2]) + cookiearray[2]);

   document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = n1 + "+" + n2 + "=" ; //displays to page
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#answer").keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            answer = $("#answer").val();
        }
    });
});
```

to detect the enter key and to retrieve the answer.
By declaring a global variable, the value you retrieve can be used by other functions in your js file.

Comment: Would it be possible for me to access this value from the addition function?

Comment: Yes because answer is a global variable